# Chrome not honoring protocol-relative URL references?

Tags: google-chrome, https, protocol-relative

I have noticed today for the first time that Chrome (and only Chrome) does not pay attention to protocol-relative URL references. For example:

```
<img src='//www.example.net/image.png />
```

should source as https when it appears on https pages, and should source as http when it appears on http pages. IE and FF are still working this way, but Chrome is now sourcing it only as

```
//www.example.net/image.png
```

so when it appears on an https page, the page becomes unsecure. Anyone else notice this recently?

Comment: Do you have an example to a test?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does respect protocol relative URL's, looking at your example it is malformed (there is no closing ' on your path.